# SAPUI5 Using promises to wait for code execution

Tags: sapui5

I'm in a loop here and for each iteration I'm calling `_checkExistingDefaultTimes` to check if a record exists.

The problem is, the code in the loop is not executed until I'm outside the for loop.

Is there any way I can use a Promise so that it forces the `.then` code (pushing oOpeningTimes) before the loop finishes?

```
var oOpeningTimes = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfDays; i++) {
this._checkExistingDefaultTimes(test.SiteInfo.SiteId,test.EffectiveDateFrom,      
 test.EffectiveDateTo)
       .then(function (bResult) {

           oOpeningTimes.push({
               temporaryDate: oDate,
               startTime1: oModelData[oWeekday].startTime1,
               endTime1: oModelData[oWeekday].endTime1,               
           });
});

oStoreData.OpeningTimes = oOpeningTimes;
oModel.setData(oStoreData);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the loop, no. The for-loop is a synchronous construct and the promise is async. What you need to do is wait until all of the promises generated in the loop are resolved before running your follow-on code. [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) is what `Promise.all` is for. You could do something like the following:

```
var oOpeningTimes = [];
var oPromises = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfDays; i++) {
oPromises.push(this._checkExistingDefaultTimes(test.SiteInfo.SiteId,test.EffectiveDateFrom,      
 test.EffectiveDateTo)
       .then(function (bResult) {

           oOpeningTimes.push({
               temporaryDate: oDate,
               startTime1: oModelData[oWeekday].startTime1,
               endTime1: oModelData[oWeekday].endTime1,               
           });
}));

Promise.all(oPromises).then(function() {
  oStoreData.OpeningTimes = oOpeningTimes;
  oModel.setData(oStoreData);
})
```

Comment: Marvellous, I'll try it tomorrow. Thank you !!